# Lua trouble: attempt to call global 'unpack' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, embedding, unpack

I am relatively new to Lua, and am experimenting with embedding it in a library. I can execute the script just fine from the command line, but I hit the following error when calling a function in my script when embedded

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API ([string "-- #! /usr/local/bin/lua..."]:72: attempt to call global 'unpack' (a nil value))
```

Where did `unpack` go?

Comment: Check the versions of Lua you are using. In Lua 5.1, `unpack` was a global, but in 5.2 it's been moved to `table.unpack`. You might be using Lua 5.1 in the command line while embedding 5.2.

Comment: Hmm moving it to table.unpack worked. I'm using 5.2.3 for both the embedded and command line interpreters. The command line interpreter did not seem to care that I left `unpack` unqualified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably embedding Lua as source, not as a pre-built library. In this case, you have probably not enabled backward compatibility.

By default, the command line interpreter is built with backward compatibility, hence the difference you see.

Comment: how do i enable backward compatibility?

Comment: @jarnosz, define [LUA_COMPAT_UNPACK](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/luaconf.h.html#LUA_COMPAT_UNPACK) or LUA_COMPAT_ALL.